# Doesn't the SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID work in the sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

i use the SetExpressCheckout for my website. On this side I have some products. Each product has an other recipient. So I fill the parameter "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID"

```
    $padata =   '&CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode($CurrencyCode).
            '&PAYMENTACTION=Sale'.
            '&ALLOWNOTE=1'.
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID='.$email.            
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode($CurrencyCode).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT='.urlencode($ItemTotalPrice).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT='.urlencode($ItemTotalPrice).
            '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0='. urlencode($ItemQty).
            '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0='.urlencode($ItemPrice).
            '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0='.urlencode($ItemName).
            '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0='.urlencode($ItemNumber).
            '&AMT='.urlencode($ItemTotalPrice).
            '&RETURNURL='.urlencode($PayPalReturnURL ).
            '&CANCELURL='.urlencode($PayPalCancelURL);
```

But when I get the success page, the array of the transaction shows the recipient of die API-Account. Is that a problem of the sandbox or is it my problem?
Thanks for your answers and help!

Comment: die API-Account..??  No idea what you mean there.  Can you show a sample of the response you're getting?

Comment: I mean the email-adresse of the development account. That's my real-account, also. I tested it in the live system, but there was the same result. Now, I'm using another script with other parameters. It's like that: "&receiverList.receiver(" . $key . ").amount=" . urlencode($value);

Comment: Did you found a solution? I have the same problem here