# PayPal Integration, how would I define the receiver account?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm working on a very small ecommerce software that allows users to put their products up in order to get customers to see them and buy them.

I would like to offer the paypal option and therefore working on creating a module for it.

I started out with this:

http://sanwebe.com/assets/paypal-express-checkout/

Which got me started pretty good, but my "problem" is now that the receiver is automatically the API username?

That is what i can see in the RECEIVEREMAIL parameter value from the response that I get from paypal after an payment.

I would like the receiver to be my users email which i got in the db. So that they get the payment directly into their account.

So I would need to specify the email/paypal account email somewhere in the code?

Hope somebody can explain me how this would be done, I can understand it may not be possible doing while in sandbox mode - but can someone clarify that API information is one thing and receiver is another?

**Update: I just found out I can have**

```
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=receiver@email.com
```

in my call to PayPal. Although this still does not work, it still shows the dev. api username.

Here's another with the same question, but left unanswered:

[Doesn't the SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID work in the sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350216/doesnt-the-sellerpaypalaccountid-work-in-the-sandbox)

Comment: I have also tried to create a sandbox business account (merchant) and then added it after SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID= and then tried to make a payment = still shows api username in RECEIVERMAIL... doesnt make sense :(

Comment: Don't know if you can do this with express checkout, as it's only available to people with business accounts and you need an API key which is linked to the sellers account. You can easily do it with a regular paypal buy now button or add to cart button, but I don't think you can set the seller dynamically with express checkout.

Comment: @Bryan thanks but I know its possible? Try to add to cart and choose Paypal here: http://vnecky.tictail.com/ and the only thing I have set up is my email in the settings. For me it looks like they are using express checkout and then just uses my email as receiver?

Comment: We re working on a very similar project, hence the bounty. Our project is using laravel, but the basic idea is the same. User signs up and creates a listing with a price, enters their paypal email (or some other auth mechanism if required), and then receives 100% of the payment for any orders.

Comment: Have `receiver_email` been tried?
Also, is there a specific reason you wold not prefer to send a personalised email to the client after you received confirmation from Paypal payment with the redirect routes you provide to them for the scenarios the payment goes through, gets rejects, etc?

Comment: @DiogoSanto the OP may be long gone - i started the bounty. I cannot find any offical paypal api docs covering this scenario, so i dont even know what api to investigate at this point. Have you dome something similar recently

Comment: Hey @Steve, thanks for the heads up, that passed me by completely! X)
As for the problem at hands, I implemented paypal a couple of years ago so unfortunately is a little blur, though I remember using UserSession between my API and Paypal and using the main page confirmation to distinguish the result and process everything from there. But I would store all the activity on my own DB as well so might be a little different from what you are after *thinking*

Answer (score 4):

Your users need to Grant API Permissions for your application to make API calls on their behalf.  Then you would still use your own API username, password, and signature, but you'd also include a SUBJECT parameter along with those.  The SUBJECT value would be the email address or PayPal merchant ID of a user who has granted permissions for your app.

Users can grant permissions manually through their PayPal profile, or you can build this into your app using the Permissions API.  If you go with the permissions API, though, you end up using tokens in the header (OAuth) as opposed to the SUBJECT parameter.

== EDIT ==

It seems that this must have been updated in an API version release or something.  I just ran the following in the sandbox with no issues.

```
[REQUESTDATA] => Array
    (
        [USER] => sandbo_1215254764_biz_api1.angelleye.com
        [PWD] => 12xxxx74
        [VERSION] => 109.0
        [BUTTONSOURCE] => AngellEYE_PHPClass
        [SIGNATURE] => AiKZhEExxxxxxxxz2qxKx96W18v
        [METHOD] => DoExpressCheckoutPayment
        [TOKEN] => EC-9SG69555XT1155150
        [PAYERID] => YW66KXBKJRRES
        [RETURNFMFDETAILS] => 1
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 100.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 80.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 15.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 5.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC] => This is a test order.
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTETEXT] => This is a test note before ever having left the web site.
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID] => sandbo_1204199080_biz@angelleye.com
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Widget 123
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0] => Widget 123
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 40.00
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0] => 123
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMURL0] => http://www.angelleye.com/products/123.php
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1] => Widget 456
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC1] => Widget 456
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1] => 40.00
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1] => 456
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1] => 1
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMURL1] => http://www.angelleye.com/products/456.php
    )
```

The payment wound up in the sandbo_1204199080_biz@angelleye.com account.  Just make sure you have the same value set in both SetExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckoutPayment and you should be fine.

Comment: How come when I created my free store on tictail.com I never had to "accept" anywhere and make tictail grant permission for my paypal account? It simply just had my email and I was ready to be the receiver? Am i missing something..

Comment: That would be if you're using Payments Standard with basic HTML forms as checkout.  That works, but it's not ideal because then people can copy the HTML code, adjust it, and then buy your product at a cheaper price.  You could counter-act this by auto-refunding within an IPN script if the price isn't accurate, but this can be a pain.

Comment: If you look at my comment on the question, and try the shopping process out on the site provided you will clearly see that there IS a way to do this without basic html form, but a real api way where its possible to have a different receiver?

Comment: SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID is only for use with parallel payments in Express Checkout, and it would only be when you, the API caller, are the one sending the payment unless you have a 3rd party user grant permissions like I said.

Comment: Are there any other way then to make a solution for Paypal where I can define the receiver? From my example and other sites, it's proven that it can be done without permissions.

Comment: Ok, use Payments Standard then.  That's how you would do it.

Comment: Ok after some research that may be it. But what I can see, I need to store data that goes to paypal via some HTML and then the button for submitting? Are there any way to go real PHP way and then redirect to paypal.. like I could with the express checkout sample? Thanks for your guidence

Comment: Just to clarify, I dont want the HTML solution because of the flaw that the user can modify the params...

Comment: Then you're going to have to use Express Checkout (or any API product) and grant permissions.  Not sure what else to tell ya, bud.

Comment: The only other way would be to have your users enter their API credentials into your app, but that's neither secure nor any easier than having them grant permission.

Comment: I may sound dum, but I really know that this can be done. Please, really, try vnecky.tictail.com - you can see at the checkout that you can choose from paypal account or credit card via paypal. Just choose any and add some false values in the user details. (both pay options are paypal and are going to the same paypal checkout page, difference is that the "Not registered" tab is shown when choosing credit card via paypal.) Could you please explain what theyre using and how they can use this without any API credentials from me, or permission grant? Thank you, this wil solve hours now of research

Comment: Forgot to mention, ofcourse after entering the user details, press Proceed to payment

Comment: They're using express checkout, but if they're making the calls on behalf of other people they must have used API permissions one way or another.

Comment: They have not granted any API permissions from me. I just dont think the permission part is required just for receiving money? Thanks for your contribution so far

Comment: In order for you to receive money via the Express Checkout API, the requests would have to be made using your API credentials or you'd have had to grant API permissions.  They could have tied this into a signup form or something so you didn't even realize it was happening.

Comment: Thats great info, I thought when granting API permissions, landing on paypal.com and accept permissions is necessary?

Comment: It is, but if they had that tied into their signup maybe you didn't even notice..??

Comment: I'm really sorry to say No, because really I would notice. Try registering yourself on tictail.com and lets solve this mystery...

Comment: Well, I stand corrected.  They must have changed this in a version release or something, because you didn't used to be able to do it.  I just ran a test in the sandbox, though, using the sellerpaypalaccountid parameter and it worked just fine.  I used API credentials for one account, set the sellerpaypalaccountid to another, and then submitted the payment with yet another sandbox account.  The payment went to the sellerpaypalaccountid account.

Comment: You can try my setup here http://bit.ly/1dJMuVN - I appreciate your time looking into this.

Comment: Appreciate your answer sir! I am still unable to set the receiver mail, so I am abit amazed that you could. Did you create sandbo_1204199080_biz@angelleye.com exist as a sandbox business merchant account?

Comment: I have now tried to set sellerpaypalaccountid to a sandbox personal account and then tried sandbox business account, none of them works and will change the receiveremail..arhhhh

Comment: I also just tried setting sellerpaypalaccountid to sandbo_1204199080_biz@angelleye.com , does not work out...

Comment: I now have the exact same use case, would you be willing to expand on this answer @DrewAngell, i have added a bounty. Paypal support have not been helpful (recommended a wordpress plugin, for a laravel project, and no hints as to what api the plugin is actually using)

Comment: @DrewAngell Sorry to bug you, do you have any feedback on this at all - i am at a loss with this, as paypals api docs are not at all clear, and there are so many apis that are seemingly EOL or not yet released.

Comment: @Steve Sorry, I haven't been hanging here as much lately.  What exactly are you stuck with at this point?  You're just trying to do permissionless payments to 3rd party recipients with Express Checkout?

Comment: @DrewAngell thank you, I am trying to facilitate 3rd party payments, via any suitable API. Simply put, we have a very simple app where a user can sign up and create events, and collect responses from invitees. We would like to give our users the ability to charge for attendance, by adding their PayPal email (or authorising via oaurh if required).

Comment: So the basic flow would be 1.sign up to our website. 2.add PayPal email (or other Auth mechanism). 3. Create event with a price. 4.add list of invitees. 5.invitee follows link to the event, fills in details and clicks pay via PayPal. 6.payment is sent to the original user who created the event.

Comment: I might just be being particularly dense, but I keep going around in circles. The last time I used PayPal APIs was 2012 with express via redirects and IPN. It looks like these APIs are EOL. I found references to the marketplace API, but that's still in restricted beta. Adaptive payments also seems to be EOL. PayPal checkout API looks nice and clean (and some what similar to stripe that I am more familiar with) but I can't unearth any mechanism to send payments to a 3rd party account

Comment: @Steve Look at PayPal Identity (Log In with PayPal).  You can use that and tie permissions into it so that you can then make 3rd party API calls.  They are lacking some documentation on it, unfortunately.  [Here's a good one](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/merchant-onboarding/permissions/), but it's specific to PayPal Here.  Just follow the same steps for whatever Scope you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this parameter:

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=someone@gmail.com
```

other parameters can be configured also for that receiver,like:

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=300
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=200
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=100
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=Summer Vacation trip
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT=0
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=0
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=someone@gmail.com
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED=false
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Order
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID=CART26488-PAYMENT0
```

Note: you can add up to 10 receivers, just change the index like:

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_.....
PAYMENTREQUEST_2_.....
```

Comment: Thanks @T.Todua, which api is this for please, and have you done this recently?